# Converting js onmousemove to touches on ios

Tags: javascript, ios, html

I'm trying to convert a HTLM5 to an iOS mobile version, to be played using touches instead of the mouse. What is the best way to access touches in the same way as `onmousemove`?

**Code for the mouse:**

```
document.onmousemove = function(e){
    if (player.X + c.offsetLeft > e.pageX) {
        player.moveLeft();
    } else if (player.X + c.offsetLeft < e.pageX) {
        player.moveRight();
    }

}
```

Comment: People may shout "what have you tried?" and throw a downvote at you. (Just so you know, I see you have just 1 reputation point and are probably new to SO.)